# I can't figure out when it is now exiting my for loop and I get runtime error 28

Tags: vba, runtime

I have the following function to find the last column in a spreadsheet that has data in it and I get a runtime error 28. I believe it is not exiting my for loop properly. Am I missing something stupid? I've made multiple simple functions exactly like this with no issues.

```
Function max_column()

Dim i As Integer
Dim max_col As Integer

For i = 1 To 200
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i) = "" Then max_col = i: Exit For
Next i
max_column() = max_col
Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: remove the `max_col = i:` from the `if` statement (note colon also removed)  ... change 3rd line from end to `max_column() = i` .... remove `Exit Function` ... remove `Dim max_col As Integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things happening here. First, you should avoid using `Integers` in favor of `Longs`. Assigning an `Integer` a value greater than 32,767. If you try to give it a value of 32,768 you will get a run-time `Overflow` error (error number 8).

Fixing that first bit would look like this:

```
Function max_column()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim max_col As Long

    For i = 1 To 200
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i) = "" Then max_col = i: Exit For
    Next i
    max_column() = max_col
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Of course, this doesnt solve the issue, it just gets rid of a common mistake that tends to lead to issues. There are a couple things far more sinister here that are likely the issue. First is that you are using an unqualified `Worksheets` reference which means you are relying on the `ActiveWorkbook` regardless of whether or not this is the intended target.

The second issue is the `:` character. This denotes a line break, without actually being a line break! How convenient...except you're missing the issue with your logic.

```
For i = 1 To 200
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i) = "" Then max_col = i: Exit For
Next i
```

Is really:

```
For i = 1 To 200
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i) = "" Then 
        max_col = i
    End If

    Exit For
Next i
```

All this loop will EVER do is return 1 or 0 since either the first cell in the second row is blank, or the loop exits.

Finally, your function return call is being called again, which is what creates the stack overflow error (since it keeps calling and calling and calling....).

Fix that to `max_colum` which really should be `GetTheFirstColumnOnTheActiveSheetThatHasANullStringValueInTheSecondRow` (notice that the actual function is not the same as a simple `max_column`).

With these changes your code becomes:

```
Function max_column()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim max_col As Long

    For i = 1 To 200
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i) = "" Then 
            max_col = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    max_column = max_col

    Exit Function
End Function
```

And with final adjustments to avoid other errors:

```
Public Function GetMaxColumn() as Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 200
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i) = vbNullString Then 
            GetMaxColumn = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Voila! A perfectly functional function.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I have very bad habits that I need to break.

Answer (score 1):

No loop needed, just use END().

This will return the first blank cell in row 2:

```
Function max_column() as Long
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1) = "" Then
        max_column = 1
    Else
        max_column = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Column + 1
    End If
End Function
```

If what you want is the column just right of the last used cell in the row use:

```
Function max_column() as Long
    max_column = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
End Function
```

Comment: If the value of `Cells(2, 1)` is `vbNullString` the End command would work differently than OP's function.

Comment: @BrandonBarney true, fixed.  See Edit.

Comment: @BrandonBarney and still do not need a loop.

Comment: Agreed, no loop is needed, but your approach could be simplified with something like `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Column + 1).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1`. Skip the ugly if block. I would still recommend explaining the approach a bit though. I imagine the OP has no clue what any of this is doing. And, in all fairness, this approach isnt functionally equivalent to OP in the event that there is a blank space between cells.

Comment: @BrandonBarney that is not how I read what the OP wants.  They are looking for the first blank. That may or may not coincide with the most last used cell in the row, or I would have used: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column +1`

Comment: TBH I think the OP's code reflects something other than intention. He notes in his question that he is trying to find the last column, but in his code it only finds the first blank column (and that is limited to the first 200 columns as well). As I noted in my edited comment, the cleaner approach is not functionally equivalent to the OP's code, so I concede that, but I still think more explanation of what the code is doing will be beneficial for the OP.

Comment: @BrandonBarney looping through Ranges is never the option.  Either Load the whole thing into an array and loop that or avoid the loop.  Looping through a range is slow as every time you refer to the worksheet it slows done the process.

Comment: Very much agreed, which is why I noted that neither of us would actually use these processes. Alas that would be a topic for CodeReview.

Comment: the 200 was just a random number I assigned. I understand that this is not a remotely robust or efficient way of finding what I am looking for. Most of my macros are for the most part very small and aren't used all that often so I often take put in the effort of error proofing or making it efficient considering they take < 5 seconds to run and I'll only use it a few times and I don't distribute them. This has admittedly led to some very bad habits that I need to work on. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3865990 now you need to choose one to mark as correct.  You do this by clicking the check mark by the answer you choose.  Choose the one that you used.  None of use will get our feelings hurt if you choose a different method.  There are pros and cons to all methods.

Comment: I chose the one that ended up helping me understand my errors the most as being correct, but I ended up using the solution without the loop. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would slightly modify your `If` statement.

```
Function max_column()

Dim i As Integer
Dim max_col As Integer

For i = 1 To 200
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i) = "" Then 
    max_col = i
    Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next i

max_column() = max_col

End Function
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I see now my exit statement was not actually within my loop.